# How can I do following thing through any code,script

Tags: com, acl, dcom

From the Start menu, click Run and type Dcomcnfg.exe.
In Component Services, click Console root, expand Component Services, expand Computers, and then click My Computer. On the Action menu, click Properties.
In the My Computer Properties dialog box, on the COM Security tab, in the Launch and Activation Permissions section, click Edit Defaults.
I want to add users to Edit Default.Can someone can provide me a code/script that does all the functions as doing this thing to each system is a tiresome job

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. At the moment there is not enough for anyone to to give an answer. You should provide more information if you want help. For example, what operating system do you have? Further, this is not a code writing service. We help programmers with their problems, so show us some code you have started with and then you can get help making it work.

Comment: Sir,I'm not getting any idea from where to access or add  users.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install the [Windows SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279) and compile the `dcomperm` sample found in

```
[SDK Installation folder]\Samples\com\fundamentals\dcom\dcomperm
```

the resulting executable (`dcomperm.exe`) enables you to edit default launch and activation permissions from the command line